# Pyside QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyside

I have a simple task.
I created a editor with the QTextEdit and I put some richtext(HTML) into it with the method setHtml().

```
editor = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
editor.setHtml("<p><font color='red'>Hello World</font></p>")
```

But when I called the method toHtml() to get the content what I set, it returns a whole HTML.

How can I get the content that I set ?

Answer (score 0):

The `toHtml()` function *converts* the current text content to html. There is no way to retrieve the original input.

If you want to keep the original input, just save it to a variable.